# Struggling to map users in Identity 2, asp.net: User to many roles per group

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to map out the following:
One user to 
Many groups where
Each user has a specific role to that group

e.g. 
User1: Tim
Tim is a member of groups A, B, C
He Has 
Role: Admin for group A
Role: Member for group B
Role: Visitor for group C

Now here's my current code:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MapGroupsToRoles.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MapGroupsToRoles.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser() { this.RolesToGroups = new List<GroupToRoles>(); }
        public ICollection<GroupToRoles> RolesToGroups { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
    public class GroupToRoles
    {
        public int GroupToRolesId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
        public ClanRole Role { get; set; }
    }
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {

        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GroupToRoles> GroupToRolesTable { get; set; }
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
        {
            modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        //    modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(u => u.Id);
            modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(u => u.Id);           
            modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.RolesToGroups).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelbuilder.Entity<GroupToRoles>().ToTable("GroupToRolesTable").HasKey(u => u.GroupToRolesId);
            modelbuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(u => u.ProviderKey);
            modelbuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(u => u.RoleId);

            modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().ToTable("Groups");
            modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().HasKey(u => u.GroupId);
            modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        }
    }

}
```

Now for my models:

```
namespace MapGroupsToRoles.Models
{
    public class ClanRole
    {
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace MapGroupsToRoles.Models
{
    public class Group
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public Group() { }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<GroupToRoles> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have managed to get some working, but if you paste this into a default MVC5 project with Identity template in you should notice:

1. The Users has NO RolesToGroups... the many to many seems to be ignored
2. The GroupToRolesTable has Group_GroupId and Group_GroupId1??? What the?!!

There's other issues but those are the ones that matter

As a final note, the reason for using ClanRoles and not the standard identity roles is because I want two sets of roles - 1 for the groups (or clans as you may have guessed) and one for the application. If there is a way of separating such (I haven't looked into it much yet) please let me know

Many thanks for any help or guidance

Comment: Have you seen this? http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/19/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Implementing-Group-Based-Permissions-Management-Part-I.aspx. I think it relates to what you are doing. It's been awhile since I read it.

Comment: Thanks Jack, yeah I have but it doesn't work with the new Identity :(

Comment: This is not the default behavior for Identity and might not always work. If I were you, I'd implement my own stores instead of using the default ones. You don't have to remove EF, if you want, just be sure to handle IRoleStore and IUserRoleStore properly and have fun =) This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652543/does-new-asp-net-mvc-identity-framework-work-without-entity-framework-and-sql-se/22677441#22677441