# asp net mvc with identity connecting to asp net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have an asp.net MVC 5 application with a cookie based authentication.

I'm now building an ASP.NET Web API with Token Based Authentication. In order to separate the UI server (web server) and the Data layer server (app server) per client request.

If I remove entity framework from the web application:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IDbContext {
     public ApplicationDbContext()
         : base("name=Database") {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
     }
}
```

and move it to web api, can I still use the default entity types for Identity Users, Roles, Claims, Logins?

or do I need to maintain 2 DBContext classes one in the web application and the other in the Web API?

Comment: Put it in its own project and reference it from the two projects. no need to maintain 2 DbContext classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652543/does-new-asp-net-mvc-identity-framework-work-without-entity-framework-and-sql-se/22677441#22677441