# Custom UserStore for ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Based on the implementation published on [GitHub](https://github.com/hiiru/AspNet.Identity.DocumentDb/blob/master/src/AspNet.Identity.DocumentDb/UserStore.cs) I have made my own **UserStore** and **RoleStore** which don't use the **Entity Framework** (I currently need only a simple list of users in memory before I attach to a real data base). To be able to do this, I had to change the registration. I have written my own [IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs) without DbContext and with TryAddSingleton instead of TryAddScoped, so once initialized list of users can last through the app lifespan. The problem is, the Dispose method is called so many times... I do not dispose anything, but there are so many calls. Is it because I made the **UserStore** and **RoleStore** singleton, even though everything else works as they were scoped?

The second thing is, what is the neccessary minimum to accomplish the working **UserStore**?

[danludwig wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657487/mvc-5-custom-userstore) you need only *IUserStore* and *IUserPasswordStore* and it is very probable, because I did a store implementing those two interfaces and a **RoleStore** with *IRoleStore* and it seemd to work. I did also the **RoleStore** because of the `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()` part in startup class. I used an **Entity Framework** authorization template for *ASP.NET Core Web Application* (with *Individual User Accounts*).

[Arve Systad and Anderson Matos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652543/does-new-asp-net-mvc-identity-framework-work-without-entity-framework-and-sql-se) wrote that you need those 8:

1. `IUserStore<TUser>`
2. `IUserPasswordStore<TUser>`
3. `IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser>`
4. `IUserClaimStore<TUser>`
5. `IRoleStore<TRole>`
6. `IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser, string>`
7. `IUserRoleStore<TUser, string>`
8. `UserManager<TUser>`

After I deleted all of the **Entity Framework** packages, I have learned that it provides only the **UserStore** and **RoleStore** which implement (based on the source code from GitHub):

1. IUserLoginStore,
2. IUserRoleStore,
3. IUserClaimStore,
4. IUserPasswordStore,
5. IUserSecurityStampStore,
6. IUserEmailStore,
7. IUserLockoutStore,
8. IUserPhoneNumberStore,
9. IQueryableUserStore,
10. IUserTwoFactorStore,
11. IUserAuthenticationTokenStore

And:

12. IQueryableRoleStore,
13. IRoleClaimStore

After deleting the packages, I tried to do a minum scenario **UserStore** and **RoleStore** for the **Entity Framework** authentication template and I got to:

1. IQueryableUserStore,
2. IUserPasswordStore,
3. IUserSecurityStampStore,
4. IUserLockoutStore,
5. IUserTwoFactorStore,
6. IUserRoleStore,
7. IUserClaimStore

And probably only IRoleStore, becasuse only a Dispose method is being called. Most of the interfaces provide only a Get... during the app lifetime. While adding a user, I get some setters called, but they come from **IQueryableUserStore**, **IUserPasswordStore**, **IUserSecurityStampStore** and **IUserLockoutStore**. Do I really need all those interfaces?

**EDIT:**

My current post-EF **UserStore** looks like this with implemented only mentioned methods:

```
public class MyUserStore<TUser> :
    IQueryableUserStore<TUser>,
    IUserPasswordStore<TUser>,
    IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>
    where TUser : MyIdentity
{
    private List<TUser> _identities = new List<TUser>();
    CreateAsync(...)
    FindByIdAsync(...)
    FindByNameAsync(...)
    GetPasswordHashAsync(...)
    GetSecurityStampAsync(...)
    GetUserIdAsync(...)
    GetUserNameAsync(...)
    SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(...)
    SetPasswordHashAsync(...)
    SetSecurityStampAsync(...)
}
```

The last thing I'd like to ask is the purpose of setter methods in **UserStore**. They mostly set some additional properties in the Identity:

```
    public async Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(TUser user, string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
        user.NormalizedUserName = normalizedName;
        await UpdateAsync(user, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Why? Is this a step for some kind of data base side validation? It's kind of weird when you check the path the app goes through while adding a new user and it starts from *SetPasswordHashAsync* and ends with *CreateAsync*... :P

Comment: the other components of Identity that depend on the stores are mostly scoped per request, so they get disposed and dispose their dependencies at the end of the request. for that reason it is best to scope your user and role stores instead of making them singleton. The EF versions of UserStore and RoleStore implement all of those I*Store interfaces. it is best to implement them also unless you are sure you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks! So it's as I thought. :) Currently I need a fixed list in memory and later I'm going to connect with a data base, but still, I'd like to avoid the EF. Maybe someone knows what interfaces are really neccessary to get the minimum auth functionality. :)

Comment: I have a very simple no database auth solution here: https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.SimpleAuth the only part of Identity it uses is the passwordhasher